# Error occurred while Archive my IOS application?

Tags: xcode, ios5, archive

I've created an IOS application,But when i'm trying to archive my project i get two errors saying-

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: have you used Static library in your project? If, it may have happened that you have built the library only for simulator(i.e for i386 processor) ,which doesn't run on device. To run it on device as well as simulator you will have to build the library universally and maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: I've edited my question(actually app not run even on simulator). Please check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes i got it, AppDelegate.m was missing from Compile sources.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. The following steps solved my problem:

- Click on the project (left upper corner on your Xcode window)
- Click on `Build Phases tab -> Compile Sources`
- Check whether `AppDelegate.m` is on the list. If not,

  - click `+` button
  - search `AppDelegate.m` and then add it.